# How to remove duplicate rows without changing the data structure

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe and i want to remove duplicate rows from multiple specific columns. How can i do so such that it doesnt remove the whole row, only those that are in the column i specified and also convert the duplicates into empty spaces or NaN.

I want the data to stay in the same position because when i remove duplicates now, it removes the whole row and also shifts up the data.

Current:

```
df = [{A:a , A:a, A:a, B:b, B:b, B:b, C:c, C:c, C:c}]
```

Expected:

```
df = [{A:a, A:Nan, A:Nan, B:b, B:Nan, B:Nan, C:c, C:Nan, C:Nan}]
```

Comment: Hello, can you show the code that leads to this result ?

Comment: Im just giving a random example. My dataset consists of several rows and columns. But i only want to remove duplicates in one column without causing the other rows to shift up and fill the deleted duplicate spaces.

Comment: Boxes = {'Color': ['Green','Green','Green','Blue','Blue','Red','Red','Red'],
         'Shape': ['Rectangle','Rectangle','Square','Rectangle','Square','Square','Square','Rectangle']
        }
df = DataFrame(Boxes, columns = ['Color', 'Shape'])

just take this example. if i were to remove duplicates in column shape, the corresponding rows in the color column would be removed as well. i want the duplicates in shape to be converted to Nan, not changing the whole structure of the dataframe